# Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqlconnector

Имеется метод `sqlExecute` который прекрасно работает если программа с одним потоком и пишет и читает и апдейтит данные.
Имеется программа которая делает запросы в базу по нескольким таймерам, которые создают разные потоки. И в этой программе часто вылетает исключение

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>
> Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.

Ошибка вылетает на строке `reader = command.ExecuteReader()`

После чего срабатывает `Catch exception As MySqlException`

В таблице всего 600 записей, по запросу достаются 5-10 записей не более.
База локальная и сетевых задержек быть не может, запросы на чтение работают мгновенно.

Изначально `command.CommandTimeout` было равно `1000`, увеличил до `10000` а потом и до `99999`, толку ноль.

Далее перед вызовом строки на которой вылетает ошибка, поставил следующий код.

```
If GConn.model.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
    Stop
End If
```

Дабы проверить, открыт ли коннект, и на команду Stop при ошибке не попадает выполнение, то есть коннект "вроде открыт".

Это синглтон коннекта `GConn.model.Connection`

Далее мои фантазии иссякли...

Сам метод:

```
    Public Function sqlExecute(ByVal str_sql As String, Optional ByVal type As Integer = 0) As Object

        Try

StartCommand:

            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand With {
                .Connection = GConn.model.Connection,
                .CommandText = str_sql
            }
            command.CommandTimeout = 99999

            command.Prepare()

            If GConn.model.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                GConn.model.Connection = New MySqlConnection(GConn.model.Connstring)

ReOpen1:
                Try
                    GConn.model.Connection.Open()
                Catch exception3 As Exception

                    If exception3.Message = "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." Then
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                        GoTo ReOpen1
                    End If

                End Try

                GoTo StartCommand
            End If

            Select Case type

                Case 0
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    command.Dispose()
                    Return command.LastInsertedId
                Case 1

                    If GConn.model.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                        Stop
                    End If

                    reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    command.Dispose()
                    Return reader
                Case 2

            End Select


        Catch exception As MySqlException

            Return Nothing

        Catch exception2 As Exception

            If exception2.Message = "The connection is not open." Then

                If GConn.model.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    GConn.model.Connection.Close()
                End If

                If GConn.model.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

                    GConn.model.Connection = New MySqlConnection(GConn.model.Connstring)
ReOpen2:
                    Try
                        GConn.model.Connection.Open()
                    Catch exception3 As Exception

                        If exception3.Message = "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." Then
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                            GoTo ReOpen2
                        End If

                    End Try

                    GoTo StartCommand
                End If

            End If

        End Try

        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

Заросы типа:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    `jos_md_visa_pool`
WHERE
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 80



SELECT * FROM
    `jos_md_visa_pool`
WHERE
    1
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 80)
AND `is_used` = '0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что использовался синглтон соединения с базой в разных потоках, а делать несколько запросов к базе по одному и тому же коннекту одновременно нельзя.

> Это синглтон коннекта `GConn.model.Connection`